# Best search algorithm to find non present

Tags: java, algorithm, list, stream, java-stream

Best search algorithm to find non present number on range of numbers

I have a follow range of numbers on array: [3, -2, -1, 5, 6,7, -9 0, 1,2,3,5,7]
On begin i change the array to Set  and i use the filter to get only the the positive numbers and i use the stream().sorted() to sort in asc.

On result list i need find the first number non-present. I implemented a search linear algorithm where i check if next value position minus the current position value is less than 2, if true, dont there non-present number between the current position value and the next position value, if false, i return this number non-present.

The problem is what dont know if there a way to better performance but i know what the linear algorithm is the most cost to search.

My code

```java
public static int nopresentnumber(int[] array) {
        if (array == null)
            return 1;
        if (array.length == 0)
            return 1;
        final List<Integer> list = 
                                Arrays.stream(array)
                                    .boxed()
                                    .filter(n -> n > 0)
                                    .sorted()
                                    .collect(Collectors.toSet())
                                    .stream()
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        final int listSize = list.size();
        if (listSize == 0)
            return 1;
        final int min = list.get(0);
        if (min > 1)
            return 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
            if (i < listSize - 1) {
                final int x = list.get(i + 1) - list.get(i);
                if (x > 1)
                    return list.get(i) + 1;
            }
        }
        return list.get(listSize - 1) + 1;
    }
```

To use on small ranges is not bad. On example the array [3, -2, -1, 5, 6,7, -9, 0, 1,2,3,5,7], the answer is 4. But if the range is a very big and have so much sequencial number the algorithm is so bad. On example orange [-100000... to -100000], the algorithm will be check 99999 times.

Comment: on a stream, you can call `.distinct()` which will eliminate the duplicates (instead of collecting to a set and then a list)

Comment: In general best case sorting complexity is O(n*logn) and the worst case searching cost in O(n). So, sorting number just to search is not a good idea.

Comment: Please give more details about your input; is it always a (shuffled) range of numbers, with just one number from the range missing, and possibly duplicates? Is the missing number necessarily positive?

Comment: @kaya3 i need the first number positive non-present on number range. In [-1,0,2,3] the answer is 1. In range [-3,-1,0] the answer is 1 too. but the range can be the very large and sequential or not and is because this i use stream to eliminate negatives numbers and i sort the numbers by ascendant. My algorithm use a  linear search algorithm and is not the better way i think

Answer (score 0):

You can use a binarySearch O(log n) complexity to search in your array.

First order your array:

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Apply a binarySearch:

```
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(array, valueToSearch)
```

binarySearch will return a value greater or equal to zero if the element is found.
Otherwise, it produces a negative value representing the place that the element should be inserted. The value produced is:

```
-(insertion point) - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 [3, -2, -1, 5, 6,7, -9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
```

The answer for this seem to be `-8` considering the fact that we are taking negative numbers into consideration and we are looking for **next** consecutive missing number.

*My below solution takes negative numbers into consideration, but if you want only positives, it shouldn't be hard to add simple `if` checks.*

---

**Snippet:**

```
import java.util.*;
class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      System.out.println(solve(new int[]{3, -2, -1, 5, 6,7, -9, 0, 1,2,3,5,7}));
    }

    private static int solve(int[] arr){
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        int minimum = arr[0];
        for(int x : arr){
            set.add(x);
            if(minimum > x) minimum = x;
        }

        int find_missing_num = minimum - 1; // just to compare with a base value.

        for(int x : arr){
            if(!set.contains(x-1)){
                if(find_missing_num == minimum - 1 && (x-1) != minimum - 1 || find_missing_num > x - 1) find_missing_num = x - 1;
            }   

            if(!set.contains(x+1)){
                if(find_missing_num == minimum - 1 && (x+1) != minimum - 1 || find_missing_num > x + 1) find_missing_num = x + 1;
            }
        }

        return find_missing_num;
    }
}
```

**Demo:** https://ideone.com/KPoiXR

---

**Algorithm:**

- First to create a `Set` and add all array values into the set.
- Second is to iterate over the array again and do checks for `array_element - 1` and `array_element + 1` existence.
- If we don't find them, we update the `find_missing_num` in our code accordingly.
- Time complexity: O(n), Space complexity: O(n) where `n` is the size of the array.

---

**To find the first missing positive(and also ignoring all negative numbers in array):**

```
import java.util.*;
class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      //System.out.println(solve(new int[]{3, -2, -1, 5, 6,7, -9, 0, 1,2,3,5,7}));
      System.out.println(solve(new int[]{-1,0,2,3}));
    }

    private static int solve(int[] arr){
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        int minimum = -1;
        for(int x : arr){
            if(x > -1){
                set.add(x);
                if(minimum > x) minimum = x;
            }
        }

        if(!set.contains(1)) return 1;

        int find_missing_num = - 1; // just to compare with a base value.

        for(int x : arr){
            if(x > -1){
              if(x-1 > 0 && !set.contains(x-1)){
                    if(find_missing_num == -1 || find_missing_num > x - 1) find_missing_num = x - 1;
              }   

              if(!set.contains(x+1)){
                  if(find_missing_num == -1 || find_missing_num > x + 1) find_missing_num = x + 1;
              } 
            }
        }

        return find_missing_num;
    }
}
```

**Demo:** https://ideone.com/0gwugF

Comment: This code will be check like full scan if range is sequential and very large like -100000 to 100000

Comment: @WeltonLeãoMachado It only goes through elements of the array and decides the answer.  What do you mean by _check like full scan if range_ ?

Comment: i need the first number positive non-present on number range. In [-1,0,2,3] the answer is 1. In range [-3,-1,0] the answer is 1 too. but the range can be the very large and sequential or not and is because this i use stream to eliminate negatives numbers and i sort the numbers by ascendant. My algorithm use a linear search algorithm and is not the better way i think

Comment: @WeltonLeãoMachado Updated my answer. It is O(n) time where `n` is size of the array.